# .net Core -- implement HSTS in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, asp.net-core, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, hsts

We would like to get an A+ from SSL labs security test. Currently the lack of HSTS is keeping us from the highest score.

What asp.net-core code would we use to implement HSTS on an ec2 server or elastic beanstalk environment?

Comment: This is just a matter of setting an HTTP header. The solution wouldn't be AWS specific at all, unless you were trying to accomplish this with CloudFront. You should be able to search for something like ".net Core set HTTP header" and find all the information you need.

Comment: I ask this in the context of AWS because it needs to be put into our deployment package, which gets deployed into Elastic Beanstalk and thereby built out automatically....   That's the thing, I did search for that and the only solution I saw was like a page of .net core code plus the use of a module or 2.

Comment: This is the main site I read on how to do it, but it seems overly complicated for a header: [https://www.softfluent.com/blog/dev/Improve-the-security-of-your-website-using-SSL-and-HSTS-with-ASP-NET-Core](https://www.softfluent.com/blog/dev/Improve-the-security-of-your-website-using-SSL-and-HSTS-with-ASP-NET-Core)

Comment: Isn't everything with .NET overly complicated? I would check what Elastic Beanstalk is using as a proxy server (IIS?) and look up how to configure HSTS headers at the proxy server.

Comment: HSTS is not supposed to be done from the Load balancer, even though https is. The header has to come from the host. I had checked that out too.

Comment: I said the proxy server (IIS) not the load balancer. The proxy server runs on the host.

Comment: We don't have any proxy servers just pure IIS servers.

Comment: I don't know what you call it in the .NET/Microsoft world. Amazon lists IIS as the proxy server for .NET Elastic Beanstalk apps, similar to Apache and Nginx for Elastic Beanstalk apps that run on Linux. All I'm saying is you should look into configuring IIS to return the HSTS header.